# C#  textbox.Text

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. На C#*e из сервера получаю данные и хочу вводит на экран в textbox*е так
textbox.Text = allData.ToString(); результат такой - System.Collections.ArrayList .
Подскажите как исправить, чтобы нормальный текст выходила?

Answer (score 3):

Метод ToString() для большинства классов не переопределен и возвращает тип объекта.
Думаю, следует посмотреть сначала что за тип данных у тетя дает сервер.

Посмотри этот пример, как увидишь как можно примерно пытаться обработать разные типы внутри ArrayList

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public void add()
    {
        list.Add("smth");
        list.Add(1123);
        list.Add(new char[] { '1', '2', '3' });

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            textBox.Text += list[i].ToString() + '\n';
        }

        textBox.Text += '\n';
        char[] myChar = (char[]) list[2];
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < myChar.Length; ++i)
        {
            textBox.Text += myChar[i];
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        add();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Вывод элементов ArrayList через запятую с помощью [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
textbox.Text = String.Join(", ", allData.ToArray);
```

Метод подходит, если у вас ArryList состоит из простых объектов.

Comment: Тут у него allData в виде ArrayList. В вашем случае только 1 уровень, но если как коллекцию то это простейший вариант.

Comment: ArrayList тоже работает. Используется перегрузка String.Join(String, Object[])

Comment: А вложенные массивы тоже так соединяет через запятую?

Answer (score 1):

Мне больше так нравится:

```
string EnumToStringConverter(IEnumerable arg)
{
   string result = "";    
   foreach (var item in arg)
   {
       //Здесь можно проверить тип элемента и если он тоже массив, то вызвать опять
       //эту же функцию. Надо проверить работает ли условие, сейчас не могу это 
       //сделать, так как работаю на компе без VisualStudio. Потом проверю хD

       if (item is IEnumerable) 
             result += EnumToStringConverter(item);
         else
             result += item.ToString();
         result += '\n';
         return result;
   }
}

//

void set()
{
    textbox.Text = EnumToStringConverter(allData);
}
```

В случае больших объемов в теле моей функции нужно будет воспользоваться `StringBuilder`. Но думаю из сервисов объемы вряд ли будут большими.

Comment: единственный нюанс - я бы сделал в виде extension метода

Comment: Сорри, не очень силен в теории, как это extension расширение реализовывается? Отдельный объект типа `EnumConverters`?

Comment: Сделать метод static и перед параметром написать this.

И ещё: метод лучше называть не `Converter`, а `Convert`

Comment: спасибо, учту в дальнейшем